# Quotient space and the need of being a closed left ideal

Tags: ideals, c-star-algebras, quotient-spaces

I have a question regarding a remark in my lecture. We defined the Nullspace $\mathcal{N}_{\phi}$ of positive form $\phi$ on a $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{N}_{\phi}=\{A\in\mathcal{A}\,|\,\phi(A^*A)=0\}$. This space is closed and a left ideal. It was mentioned that we can therefore consider the quotient space $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{N}_{\phi}$. Why do we need these properties? (I thought about the equivalence relation, but I didn't see it)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\mathcal N_\phi$ is a left ideal is what allows you to show that it is a subspace. You don't need the language, though, as what one does is to use Cauchy-Schwarz to show that
$$
\mathcal N_\phi=\{A:\ \phi(BA)=0\ \text{ for all } B\}. 
$$
This lets you show that $\mathcal N_\phi$ is a closed subspace, and hence the quotient space and the inner product are well-defined.

Comment: Do you need that $\mathcal{N}_\phi$ is topologically closed though? The quotient vector space (as an algebraic space) is well-defined without this condition.

Comment: Yes, you are  right that the algebraic quotient needs no topological property from $\mathcal N_\varphi$. If it were not closed the sesquilinear form would not be an inner product.